# How to animate in a new component upon clicking a button in angular?

Tags: html, css, angular, css-animations, angular-routing

I want to activate a different "sign up page" when I click the "sign up" button on my "sign in page".

If you are confused, please refer the below link. I want to recreate what's given here in angular.

https://old-frog-6056.animaapp.io/

Should I make the sign up and sign in components as two different components? Or should I create one as the child of the other?

How do I do this? Should I just use CSS animations or employ Angular routing?

Comment: It's up to you if you want to use a route animation, angular animations api, or plain css animations. Same component, different components. Any or all would work. Whatever you feel is the best way so that you can develop it, update it, test it. The animations api is nice because you can use :leave, which saves a lot of pain trying to animate a component before it is destroyed. If it were me, I would probably create different components and use a route animation.

Comment: What have you tried so far?